# Is there any way to recover deleted menu from database sql backup

Tags: menus, database

i accidently deleted my main menu but i have a .sql database backup file and i want to recover my menu from this file. Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the problem with explained here : http://marketermatt.com/export-navigation-menus/

But i would like to warn the people that will try this solution, you have to have a database backup of WordPress system which has Menu that you would like to revert

1. BackUp your WP database to your PC (bacause, you will use this for
   reverting back your system to current site)
2. Restore your database that contains correct menu
3. Install [WordPress Menu Exporter](http://wordpress.org/plugins/menu-exporter/) plugin (i've used on WP 4.0)
4. Export your Menu
5. Restore your database which you backed-up in 1st step (bacause it is your updated/current site)
6. Delete your current menu (otherwise all menus will be exist twice)
7. Import your menu with Wordpress Importer

It worked for me...